# Chrome closing after long Selenium execution

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, user-interface, crash

My goal is to get comments data from a website. Feedback is in different div region/ class.

I am able to get data until i reach certain point but after more then 20 minute of execution, comments loading slowly and chrome closing itself. Test fails with unable to find element. I am using below Chrome options and new selenium 4 feature devtools to block this issue.

using bonigarcia along with selenium 4.

Can anyone advice me anything to fasten this execution?

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
        //options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("-disable-cache");
        //options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        //options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-javascript");
        options.addArguments("--lang=en");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);




        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(100000000)));
        devTools.send(Network.setCacheDisabled(true));
```

Comment: Also tried clearing local memory in every next comment page in a loop. Still having slowness and chrome closing or comments not loading anymore

Answer (score 0):

No fix for this, loading more items increases the memory of the chrome that is why you are facing an issue.